# Looking for an easy way (or the "right way") to filter and search SQL Server database rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a smallish SQL Server (max size is less than 1GB) and I need to be able to run quite a few chained queries on the data.

My database looks a bit like this:

```
id | val1 | val2 | val3 | val4 | date_modified
1  | 'asd'| '1'  | 'd'  | 'u'  | 'xx/xx/xxxx'
```

The data I really need from this table is quite complicated. For each unique value of `val4` I need to find the two most recent rows based on the `date_modified` row. With these two entries (well, 2 entries for each unique `val4` value) I need to search all the columns in this for a regular expression, and then return the row(s) that match.

I've tried playing around with a stored procedure to do all of this, but it becomes quite complicated because I'm trying to chain the queries together in an algorithmic sort of way. I'm not sure if the way I'm going about it is wrong, or if it's easier to use some sort of java/spring abstraction layer to make this easier. I've considered just reading the entire DB into a java collection so I can apply an algorithm to it, but I don't know if that's a viable solution given how large this DB could become.

Sample data:

```
id  val1                                      val4  date_modified
1   \"test\" : \"123\", \"test2\" : \"555\"    'a'  now
2   \"test\" : \"123\", \"test2\" : \"555\"    'a'  2 hours ago
3   \"test\" : \"123\", \"test2\" : \"555\"    'a'  5 hours ago
4   \"test\" : \"123\", \"test2\" : \"555\"    'b'  10 hours ago
5   \"test123\" : \"123\", \"test2\" : \"555\"  c'  now
```

So if I search for "test" it would return:

1, 2, 4, 5 because:

1 & 2 contain "test" in their val1 columns, and they are the two most recent entries with a value4 of 'a'. 4 also contains "test" and is the most recent of val4 'b' and 5 for the same reason.

Comment: _For each unique value..._ That is the very common "first in group" (here - first 2 in group) question which has been answered many times. TSQL does not support regular expressions so the second requirement likely cannot be implemented easily - but "search ... for regular expression" is not quite clear either. Your very political avatar does not inspire more help.

Comment: `The data I really need ...return the row(s) that match` Not sure where a regex comes in, but it'd probably be easier for someone to advise if you posted a more complete data sample.  Post the table structure and some sample rows (CREATE TABLE and INSERT ....) and the expected results.

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: @SOS  tried to provide some sample data. The columns will contain json blobs. When there was no requirement to only search for the 2 most recent entries of a unique val4 value, I was using a LIKE clause to get this data.

Comment: @Astrum - So the "2 most recent dates" is the first check? Also, 1) what are the actual column data types (it's hard to tell from the sample)? I'm guessing `date_modified` = datetime and `val1=nvarchar? Also, does `val1` actually contain well formed JSON, because SQL Server does have some json functionality, just mentioning..

Comment: @sos Yes, I need to run the LIKE clause on the two most recent rows for each unique val4. So just to elaborate, there could be 5 rows with the same val4, but I only need to LIKE clause the two most recently modified ones (based off of the date_modified column). All columns are varchar(100) except for the date, which is datetime. The columns do contain proper JSON but we're just using varchar.

Comment: @Astrum - Then try Kendle's answer below to start with. Filtering to get the top 2 most recent rows first, then filter. I suspect neither LIKE nor JSON functions will be a speed demon, but you might also look into [indexing options for JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/index-json-data?view=sql-server-ver15). Also, I'd suggest profiling all options and comparing the execution plans to see which is best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use rank in a CTE and use rank() as follows to get the first 2 most recent values.
After that you can use `LIKE` in the outer query or use regex in Java as you find works best.

```
with cte as
(
  Select Id, val1,val2,val3,val4,
  date_modified,
  Rank() over(partition by val4 
      Order by date_modified desc) 
      as ranking
)
Select * from cte 
where ranking <=2
/* Add like condition here? */
Order by id
```